# Translation files are not read from mirco frontend angular application

Tags: angular, localization, translation, micro-frontend

I am trying to read ar.json & en.json from the micro frontend application but it only read it from the other angular application where I call the micro frontend app.
I see this resource "https://levelup.gitconnected.com/a-new-approach-to-i18n-in-angular-d46476b9874e" that gives example how to read these json files from micro frontend but there are some missing details:

1. The "CustomLoader" class where it is put in the project and how it is called or used
2. `${this.url}/microfrontend1Assets: what is that url and what is "microfrontend1Assets" is it the assets folder? if yes, why in proxy.conf.json it has ""target": "http://localhost:4201","
3. What is "target": "http://localhost:4201",? it is of the main app or the micro frontend app
   Thanks in advance.

Comment: The author has his repo where you can clone and run the code [link](https://github.com/HaasStefan/ngx-locutus), other than that were you successful?